# Why there is no change to the height of a cube immersed in a fluid when the container is kept in a lift going against gravity?

Tags: reference-frames, acceleration, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, buoyancy

> In a container filled with fluid (say water), and if I keep a cube (having less density than that of fluid)
> and the height of the cube submerged in fluid be $h$, then if I were to keep the system (the container) in a lift accelerating up, why doesn't the height $h$ change?

---

I Know that height submerged is equal to Specific gravity * Side length $a$, but is there a proper explanation on why the height submerged is independent of the acceleration of the system?

> And would the height be the same even when I give the system a huge acceleration (Assuming the liquid is still incompressible despite the pseudo forces acting on it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that in the frame of reference of a lift accelerating upwards, the effective gravitational field strength is increased. This affects equally the effective weight of the body, and the effective weight of fluid per unit volume, on which the Archimedean upthrust on the body depends.

So instead of
$$\text{mass of body} \times g = \text{mass of displaced fluid} \times g$$
We have
$$\text{mass of body} \times g' = \text{mass of displaced fluid} \times g'$$
in which $g'$ is the effective $g$ in the lift.
So, in terms of submerged mass, and therefore submerged volume, the equilibrium condition is unaffected.